# JS map для вывода элементов списка

Tags: javascript

Подскажи, пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка, почему элементы на залетают в список ?

```js
const goods = {
  13245345: {
    name: "Финик",
    rubles: 390,
    hryvnia: 129.09,
  },
  2456: {
    name: "Изюм",
    rubles: 190,
    hryvnia: 62.89,
  },
  434: {
    name: "Кешью",
    rubles: 999,
    hryvnia: 330.67,

  },
};

const list = document.querySelector(".goods_list");

goods.map((el, index) => {
      return (
        list.append(`<li><p>Имя: ${el.name}</p><p>Цена: ${el.rubles}</p></li>`;)
      );
    });

    console.log("good = ", good);
```

```html
<ul class="goods_list"></ul>
```

Comment: "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",

Comment: Поправил, но вывода все равно не происходит....

Comment: Сделайте good массивом!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const goods = {
  13245345: {
    name: "Финик",
    rubles: 390,
    hryvnia: 129.09,
  },
  2456: {
    name: "Изюм",
    rubles: 190,
    hryvnia: 62.89,
  },
  434: {
    name: "Кешью",
    rubles: 999,
    hryvnia: 330.67,

  },
};

const list = document.querySelector(".goods_list");

Object.values(goods).map((el) =>
  list.innerHTML += `<li><p>Имя: ${el.name}</p><p>Цена: ${el.rubles}</p></li>`);
```

```html
<ul class="goods_list"></ul>
```

Но если все-таки надо изменить `goods`:

```js
const goods = {
  13245345: {
    name: "Финик",
    rubles: 390,
    hryvnia: 129.09,
  },
  2456: {
    name: "Изюм",
    rubles: 190,
    hryvnia: 62.89,
  },
  434: {
    name: "Кешью",
    rubles: 999,
    hryvnia: 330.67,

  },
};

const list = document.querySelector(".goods_list");

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(goods)) {
  goods[k] = `<li><p>Имя: ${v.name}</p><p>Цена: ${v.rubles}</p></li>`;
  list.innerHTML += goods[k];
}
```

```html
<ul class="goods_list"></ul>
```

Comment: Но тут уж впринципе лучше `forEach`.